# Userform design time: Move controls with arrowkeys

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

Is there any way to arrange the controls in the userform using only arrowkeys (not dragging) ?

[image: Example]

Comment: Yes, if you add a 'Key Press' event, determine which control has focus, which key was pressed.  But how 'far' do you move a control?  oops - just noticed this is Excel - different animal - may not work...

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, actually I need that in design time, in the VBE interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Designer does not seem to support this and the form does not seem to capture Arrow Keys as key press events.

I have tried hacking this together with number keys but it will not keep the values of where the element was placed and does not work inside any control that actually accepts input.

So I think the answer is No you cannot use the arrow keys to move controls.

Comment: I had a little hope that it would be possible, but unfortunally it isnt. I dont understand why MS do not upgrade this IDE and this IDE only. Even in Office 2013 still same poor VBE. Sad thing...